# Mix of html and code in foreach in razor

Tags: c#, loops, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to create bootstrap grid with row-fluid class. It is need to separate all nested div's with span4 class into blocks. So I want to have html like this:

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
```

And I have code in razor

```
@{
int counter = 3;
}
@foreach (var config in Model)
{
    @if (counter == 3)
    {
       <div class="row-fluid">
       @counter = 0;
    }
    @Html.Partial("_ConfigBar", config)

    @if (counter == 2)
    {
        </div>
    }
    @{counter++;}
}
```

Partial view just put div with span4 class, and there are nothing interesting.

But it didn't work. Can anyone point me what is wrong?

Comment: What's the html output? also, what's your `Model` type?

Comment: I think that is not significant what model type is. Nevertheless it's @model IEnumerable<PercConfigEntry>. And the error is that foreach block has no "}" symbol.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Something like this should create what you need:

```
@{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var config in Model)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
           @Html.Raw("<div class=\"row-fluid\">")
        }
        else if (counter > 0 && counter % 3 == 0 )
        {
           @Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"row-fluid\">")
        }

        @Html.Partial("_ConfigBar", config)

        counter++;
    }

    @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

This will:

- create an opening div on the first loop
- close the current open div and open a new div on each 4th loop
- add a closing div once the looping is complete.

Comment: Why the `Html.Raw()`? Razor lets you mix code blocks with HTML blocks easily without the Raw() function. you only need it when you explicitly want to disable html-encoding on the value.

Comment: Because razor will complain about the multiple open/closed tags in the `if` statements

Comment: @Digbyswift, thanks for You, and for explanation why it not works.